# One database per user

Tags: php, mysql, database, sqlite, codeigniter

I am developing a php application using CodeIgniter. I am planning to split the single MySQL database to multiple sqlite databases. That is, one database(MySQL/PostgreSQL/SQLite) that handles authentication and one sqlite database per user that holds information related to users. I do not use any joins and it will have more reads than writes.

Is it a good idea to split the database into multiple sqlite databases for speed? Also, will it have problem when scaling to multiple servers? I can use redirection depending on user to point to right server.

**Edit:**
Decided to use MariaDB as my server for all users.

Comment: Generally: no, it's a terrible idea. Do you have any particularly specific scenario in which you can proof that several SQLite databases have clear advantages over a single MySQL server or cluster thereof? If not: it's not going to be faster.

Comment: Why not just a row into a user table? Is that so bad to you?

Comment: When the database grows in size, the index size increases and may slow down the website as whole. By splitting the database into multiple files, the growth rate is less.

Also if I have to move to different server, I can use same databases instead of recreating on new server with current dump.

Comment: MySQL has been proven to work just fine with databases in the range of many *terabytes*. Start worrying when you get to that size. Also, the job of indexes is to grow, that's what they do. That doesn't mean they're getting slower. Even then, there are solutions to deal with giant databases. Splitting them into smaller SQLite databases is not the answer. Proof that it's a problem before you start to worry about it.

Comment: Have you analysed how you'll handle the deployment of database changes without wiping out existing data? IMHO, it's a key point.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I can use [link](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/forge.html) to modify tables. I know its a costly operation, but its use case is low. And I can also execute those commands only when database is accessed needing to update only for active users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By splitting data into multiple sqlite databases, instead of speed, you will gain major headache and time sink. Don't do this, unless you know you have to, and can prove it with hard numbers, not hypothetical scenarios.

The advice above applies if the system you're building has some value (will be used commercially, etc.). Of course, if this is just a toy/training project, you're welcome to do whatever you like, and learn from it.

Comment: I am planning to have each user database in separate user directory. So for user ID one, I may have user_1.database. Since user ID is known from primary login, the sqlite access will be handled automatically by constructing path from user ID.

Comment: I am also worried about porting database to new server. The SQL dump will be huge if I have to port to different server and sqlite is fine for 100K hits/day and I may not reach the number anytime soon, but I do not want to worry when it reaches the limit.

Comment: sql dump has excellent compression ratio, ~90% (give or take a few percents). Just zip it before transferring. :)